# Warning: require(/home/eg./public_html/mydata/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream:

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, cpanel

There are many issues on this stack overflow already which answers composer has to be installed. I have installed composer  in my channel (bin) folder. Composer of version `Composer version 1.1.1 2016-05-17 12:25:44`. But then when i try run my project i get this error.

What else must i do?

In my index file  this is how it looks

**index**

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../app/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

**error**

```
Warning: require(/home/e.g./public_html/mydata/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/eg/public_html/mydata/index.php on line 24

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/eg/public_html/mydata/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/eg/public_html/mydata/index.php on line 24
```

Comment: The "e.g." dots in the require error seem incosistend with the "eg" in the path of the actual file. Maybe try looking if you home path is responsible for the error!

Comment: @Niels Just a typo. I just edited that part. security reasons :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is obvious and you've already run it, but you should run:

```
composer install
```

to install all project dependencies.

Comment: i get this error  This package requires php >=7.0.0 but your PHP version (5.6.29) does not satisfy that requirement.   How do i change the php version of my cpanel ?

Comment: This should be in your hosting provider help center. Of course it might be impossible to change PHP version if your hosting provider doesn't support it yet.

Comment: You can change the php version using MultiPHP from your cPanel account web interface